# Написание регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пожалуйста, помогите написать регулярку. Есть вот такой код:

```
foreach ($times as $value) { 
    $exp = '/([^\)]+)\((.*)\)/';
    $res = preg_match($exp, $value, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

который возвращает  вот это:

```
(
    [0] => [1234](56 789)
    [1] => [1234]
    [2] => 56789
)
Array
(
    [0] => [1011](1213)
    [1] => [1011]
    [2] => 1213
)
```

Как видно, под регулярку попадают круглые скобки, можно ли дописать регулярное выражение, чтоб под него попадали и квадратные скобки?

Comment: Экранировать квадратную скобку аналогично круглой.

Comment: Нет, мне надо, чтоб попадали под одно выражение и квадратные и круглые скобки.

Comment: @Стас Сидорюк, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

вариант 1

```
$exp = '/[\(\[](.+?)[\)\]][\(\[](.+?)[\)\]]/';
```

вариант 2

```
$exp = '/[\d\s]+/';
$res = preg_match_all($exp, $value, $matches);
```